# Even if federation's ha is set, the message will still be lost

Tags: activemq-artemis

I want to build a system for remote backup through Artemis. When one server shuts down, another remote server will take over its work and ensure that no messages will be lost during the service transmission.
In this way, the federation can establish queues between remote servers, and the ha option can ensure message integrity.

According to [the ActiveMQ Artemis federation documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/federation-queue.html):

> ha. This optional parameter determines whether or not this bridge should support high availability. True means it will connect to any available server in a cluster and support fail-over. The default value is false.

When I set the `ha` option to `true` and shut down the working server I found that another server will take over the work of receiving messages, but some messages still stay in the shutdown server.
Does this mean that federation's ha can only guarantee uninterrupted services and cannot synchronize data between different servers?
Is there no guarantee that messages will not be lost during fail-over?

I know the [HA Policies](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html), but it only applies to clusters, right?

> - The replicating live and backup pair must be part of a cluster.
> - Also each node, live and backups, will need to have a cluster connection defined even if not part of a cluster. The Cluster Connection info defines how backup servers announce there presence to its live server or any other nodes in the cluster.

I think it does not apply to the "Federation" chapter.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have updated my question.

Comment: "When one server shuts down, another remote server will take over its work and ensure that no messages will be lost during the service transmission." What you're describing here is a live/backup pair. This is configured via `ha-policy` as described in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html). Federation does *not* provide this kind of functionality, and I'm puzzled why you think it does. The `ha` parameter used for federation controls whether or not the bridge itself will failover between a live and backup.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. I messed up the definition of ha between cluster and federation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Artemis supports two different strategies for backing up a server shared store and replication. Those strategies allow persistent message data to survive a failover, see the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html) for further details.

Comment: I know the HA Policies, but it only applies to clusters, right? "The replicating live and backup pair must be part of a cluster,"  I think it does not apply to the "Federation" chapter.